# How do I drop only contiguous rows (all but one) in a pandas DataFrame according to column values?

Tags: pandas, drop-duplicates

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
  Column1  Column2 
0     cat        A 
1     cat        B 
2     cat        C 
3     dog        D 
4     dog        E 
5     cat        F
```

I want to drop all but one of the contiguous rows where Column 1 has duplicate values. Thus, I want to drop rows 1, 2, and 4, but I want to keep rows 0, 3, and 5. If I'm not mistaken, drop_duplicates almost works but will drop row 5. Cat and dog may show up many times in later rows, but again I only want to keep one of any contiguous rows.

I tried df.drop_duplicates(subset='cat', keep='first'), but it dropped row 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
out = df.groupby(df['Column1'].ne(df['Column1'].shift()).cumsum()).head(1)
```

Output:

```
  Column1 Column2
0     cat       A
3     dog       D
5     cat       F
```